# Repeated query parameter in Angular 2 Routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am converting an existing application over to Angular 2 and have a requirement where a query parameter can appear zero or more (i.e. repeated) times. An example would be a url that has multiple parameters for sorting (as in `#/results/data;sort=column1;sort=column2`) or when calling Solr instances and specifying multiple facet filtering (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq(FilterQuery)Parameter). Typically, the receiving endpoint recognizes those repeated parameters and presents them as an array.

How can I do this with Angular 2 routing? I am using RC4 with the 3.0-beta-2 router. When I subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute` and look at the `params`, only the last repeated value is returned, yet I know the full url is being passed in since `Location.path()` shows what was typed.

For example, given the following url

```
https://localhost:44300/#/search;fq=efg:456;q=xyz;fq=abc
```

`console.log(this.location.path(false));` shows `/search;fq=efg:456;q=xyz;fq=abc`

but only `Object {fq: "abc", q: "xyz"}` is given back with

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

this is supported since a while already.

**orginal**

This is currently not supported.
There is an open issue to get support for multiple values eventually.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9477

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @jcroll great! Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Update: this should now be [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11373).

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   // assuming ?foo=a&foo=b&bar=c
   // should return an object {'foo': ['a', 'b'], 'bar': 'c'}
   console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing complex data between views I think you would be better suited using a service injected into each of the components rather than query parameters.

Comment: the posting has nothing to do with passing data between views. It has to do with building a url and passing parameters into a *single view* where the parameter names can be repeated.